# mega.py | скачивание файлов

Tags: python, файлы

если я хочу скачать файл с mega.nz, используя mega.py, то файл скачивается пустым.
Вот мой код:

```
mega = Mega()
m = mega.login("", "")

file = m.find('data.txt')
m.download(file)
```

В директории со с скриптом создаётся файл `data.txt`, и с весов в 0 байт, но на mega.nz, он весит 29 байт.

В чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: Мб `mega.py` уже не поддерживает API того сайта

Comment: Мало вероятно, ведь я до сих пор могу загружать туда файлы, и получать список файлов

Comment: Загружать и получить список файлов через объект `Mega`? Кст, а что находится в переменной `file`? Случаем не ссылка на `data.txt`? В вашей ситуации я бы посмотрел в репозитории этой библиотеки есть ли баги как у вас и мб создал. Кроме того, код, наверняка, открыт поэтому можно самостоятельно посмотреть что выполняется в `find` и `download`.